# How do I align segments of rope to connect adjacent segments?

Tags: rotation, godot, rope-physics

[I have made a 2D rope in Godot using this thread here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/203789/object-not-rotating-properly-towards-player).

The problem I am facing now is that the rope is not rotating towards player. I have tried `look_At` but it only works when I shoot on the right side.

Here is how it's looking now:

[image: Bug - misaligned]

I want the rope segments to match together like this. This is when I shoot straight up:

[image: Aligned]

Answer (score 0):

I see my prior answer didn't rotate the rope pieces.

We had `rope_direction`, we can get an angle from it:

```
var rope_angle := rope_direction.angle()
```

And give that rotation to the pieces:

```
rope.global_position = rope_piece_position
rope.global_rotation = rope_angle
```

Actually I think you need to offset the angle. An angle of zero is to the right (on the x axis), but without rotation it works upwards. That is an offset of a quarter turn. So, try this:

```
rope.global_rotation = rope_angle - 0.25 * Tau
```